# Microsoft excel 2010 - highlight duplicate values in multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate, highlighting

I have been looking at a lot of help articles about how to highlight duplicate values, but I can't find one that does exactly what I am trying to do.

I was hoping to highlight cells when the value in the 1st cell in column 1 equals the value in the 1st cell in column 2, and the same all the way down. So if `A5=B5` I want it to be highlighted, but not highlight if `A5=B6`, and not highlight if `A5=A6`.

This is a visual example:

```
 1  3
 4  5
*2  2*
 3  1
*5  5*
 7  1
 4  2
```

So you can see, the two `4`s in the first column aren't highlighted, because I don't want duplicates highlighted in the same column. And the two `3`s in both columns aren't highlighted, because I don't want them highlighted unless they're in the same row.

I hope this makes sense. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Select column A or whatever range you'd like the formatting to apply to and use the following formula under conditional formatting (select to use a formula for the criteria)

```
=a5=b5
```

choose whatever fill you'd like

Comment: Have fun visiting the [review](http://superuser.com/review) queues, which are accessible to you now that you have > 500 reputation points (and congratulations).

Comment: Thank you. It's an honor and a pleasure to join the ranks.